# PHP/HTML - I want to loop, in a table, a DIV ID for as many items I have in my table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table which will have DYNAMICALLY CREATED checkboxes which are put into a divid (blah) isn't being looped. I want the same checkboxes to appear for each row in the table.

**Obviously the divid is not being looped as I cannot loop an id due to its nature of needing to be unique.**

Your help will be welcome.

```
  function myFunction() {
          var checkedvalue = "";
          var arrChecks = document.getElementById("blah").getElementsByTagName('input');

          for (i = 0; i < arrChecks.length; i++) {
              //var attribute = arrChecks[i].getAttribute("checked");
              //if (attribute == elementName) {
                  // if the current state is checked, unchecked and vice-versa
                  if (arrChecks[i].checked) {
                      arrChecks[i].checked = false;
                  } else {
                      arrChecks[i].checked = true;
                      checkedvalue = checkedvalue + " " + arrChecks[i].value;
                  }

              //} else {
              //    arrChecks[i].checked = false;
              //}
          }

          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedvalue;
      }


      function makeCheckboxes(str) {
          var a = document.getElementById("blah");
          var arr = str;
          var returnStr = "";
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              returnStr += '<input type="checkbox" name="theCheckbox" value="' + arr[i].checkname + '" />' + arr[i].checkname;
          }
          a.innerHTML = returnStr;
      }

      window.onload = function () {
          var arrt = js_obj_data;

          makeCheckboxes(arrt);
      };

  </script>







  <?php 

   $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
  $i = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
   $userid = $row["userID"];
   $firstname = $row["firstname"];
   $lastname = $row["lastname"];
   $year = $row["yeargroup"];
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td class="py-1">
  <?php echo $year?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $firstname?> <?php echo $lastname?> </td>                       
  <td id="blah"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: the key is, use classes. Or append an numeric value to each id

Comment: How you get your array `js_object_data` and what do you have in it?